# Can vanilla JavaScript do everything that jQuery can do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the answer is yes, then that's that, but if the answer is no, what enables it to have extra functionality over what can be done in vanilla JS?

Edit: At the time I was unaware that `$` was a valid variable name.

Comment: Isn't jQuery written in javascript?

Comment: @MarkMeyer It would appear so. I was unaware of that though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. JQuery is basically a library written in javascript, which aims to improve Developer experience.

Comment: Wow 6 upvotes for an answer that should be a comment.